# Compressing a 3D array into a 2D image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have a stack of images in a numpy array such that.

```
image_stack.shape
```

outputs (36,51,51). I have 36 images that are 51 by 51 pixels. Basically, these 36 images are patches of a larger image. I need to rearrange these patches to form one large image that is 9 by 4 patches, where the first four images of the stack would be in the first row of the large image, the next four 2nd row, etc. I was trying to mess around with reshape, but I guess I am just not seeing the right trick or understanding it correctly. Thanks

Comment: use indexing. make a big enough variable to store the new image `new_img = np.zeros((9*51,4*51))`  then the top left image can be assigned like `new_img[0:51, 0:51] = img[0,:,:]`  make a double loop to index the other ones.

Comment: What have you tried already then? It would be helpful to see _where_ you went wrong with reshape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR, use:

```
out = arr.reshape(9, 4, 51, 51).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(9 * 51, 4 * 51)
```

---

You need a combination of reshaping and transposing. Consider the following smaller example:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.multiply.outer(np.arange(1, 7), np.ones((3, 3), dtype=int))
```

which looks like:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 4]],

       [[5, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 5]],

       [[6, 6, 6],
        [6, 6, 6],
        [6, 6, 6]]])
```

Consider that we want to arrange and concatenate the patches to a 3 x 2 patched image. We can do it as follows:

```
out = arr.reshape(3, 2, 3, 3).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(9, 6)
```

out:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
       [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
       [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]])
```

Explanation:

```
# H = patch height
# W = patch width
# X = grid height (i.e. number of patches to put along the first axis)
# Y = grid width (i.e. number of patches to put along the second axis)

X, Y, H, W = 3, 2, 3, 3

out = (
    arr                     # (X Y) H W
    .reshape(X, Y, H, W)    #  X Y H W
    .swapaxes(1, 2)         #  X H Y W     
    .reshape(X * H, Y * W)  # (X H) (Y W)
)

# Note that reshaping can only ever "regroup" axes,
# and that transposing can only ever reorder "groups" of axes.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`numpy.block`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.block.html), you can construct the desired array by tiling the subarrays into a 2D with list the desired form. This list will look something like

```
[
    [image_stack[0], image_stack[1], image_stack[2], image_stack[3]],
    [image_stack[4], image_stack[5], image_stack[6], image_stack[7]],
    ...
    [image_stack[32], image_stack[33], image_stack[34], image_stack[35]],
]
```

which can be constructed using some basic list comprehensions:

```
target_shape = (9, 4)

result = np.block(
    [
        [
            image_stack[col + target_shape[1]*row, ...]
            for col in range(target_shape[1])
        ]
        for row in range(target_shape[0])
    ]
)
print(result.shape)  # (459, 204) == (9*51, 4*51)
```